# returning scikit-learn object while using Joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, numpy-ndarray, joblib

I have a numpy array, and I am using sklearn to transform the array along the first axis. I also want to save the transformer object in a dict to use later in the code.
Here is my code:

```
scalers_dict = {}
for i in range(train_data_numpy.shape[1]):
    for j in range(train_data_numpy.shape[2]):
        scaler = QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=60000, output_distribution='uniform')
        train_data_numpy[:,i,j] = scaler.fit_transform(train_data_numpy[:,i,j].reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)
        scalers_dict[(i,j)] = scaler
```

My train_data_numpy is of shape `(60000, 28,28)`. The problem is that this takes a very long time to process (train_data_numpy is MNIST dataset). I have an AMD Ryzen 5950X with 16 cores and I would like to parallelize this piece of code.

I know for example I could write something like this:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=16)(delayed(QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=60000, output_distribution='uniform').fit_transform)(train_data_numpy[:,i,j].reshape(-1,1)) for j in range(train_data_numpy.shape[2]))
```

But this doesn't return the scaler object, and I don't know how to utilize Joblib for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dask-ML](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) which is implemented on the top of [Dask Library](https://dask.org/), yet it is compatible with `scikit-learn`.

[Installation](https://ml.dask.org/install.html?#installation):

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask-ml

or

pip install dask-ml
```

### Example

```
import time
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer as skQT
from dask_ml.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer as daskQT

# toy big dataset for testing
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000000, n_features=100, random_state=2021)

# Comparison

scaler = skQT()
start_ = time.time()
scaler.fit_transform(X)
end_ = time.time() - start_
print("No Parallelism -- Time Elapsed: {}".format(end_))


# Using Dask ML
scaler = daskQT()
start_ = time.time()
scaler.fit_transform(X)
end_ = time.time() - start_
print("With Parallelism -- Time Elapsed: {}".format(end_))
```

### Result

```
No Parallelism -- Time Elapsed: 18.680
With Parallelism -- Time Elapsed: 2.982
```

---

**My Device Specs:**

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz

Number of Cores: 12
```